# Ruby Double ".." on integers with iterations

Tags: ruby

I'm sorry if I may have missed a documentation topic on this.

What does the double dot mean on this piece of code:

```
require 'benchmark'
iterations = 1000000

b = Benchmark.measure do
  for i in 1..iterations do
    x = i
  end
end

c = Benchmark.measure do
  iterations.times do |i|
    x = 1
  end
end

puts b
puts c
```

I am new to Ruby so please be easy on me :P

Comment: Using `for` is unidiomatic in Ruby.

Comment: Also, x=i vs x=1 is strange when benchmarking 'for in' against 'times'.

Comment: this is just an example from the book Beginning Ruby :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`..` indicates a `Range` object going from the number on the left to the number on the right. This can be best shown by converting the object to an `Array` object, like this:

```
>> (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

See? This object provides a range of digits from 1 through to 10.

It also works for sequential letters:

```
>> ("a".."j").to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

The `Range` class includes the `Enumerable` module which gives us the `each` method, allowing us to iterate over each element inside the range.

***Additonal trivia***:

`...` is also used in Ruby, except it gets everything up to but not including the value on the right.

```
>> (1...10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a range. The documentation for the `Range` class is [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html).

Comment: That doesn't even begin to explain what a Range is. It only shows the methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

`..` operator defines a range that you can iterate on.

Like `(1..5).to_a => [1,2,3,4,5]`

For completeness sake, you also have the `...` operator, which will leave out the last element of the range, as `(1...5).to_a => [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Just to be correct, I don't think that `..` is technically an operator. I think it's rather a language construct, more similar to a decimal point, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a range from 1 to the number of iterations

here's a quick example

```
>> for i in 1..10 do
?>   puts i
>> end
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
=> 1..10
```